How to properly package a Node.js and React app stripping the container of all unneeded files?
I have a Node.js backend that serves up the React frontend (later I can do CDN probably) and for now, I plan on disallowing CORS so React must talk to my Node.js backend only. The prototype for this is on GitHub.
What I am trying to figure out is how to launch this in a docker container but stripped of all the extra files (such as all the *.ts files found in node_modules). Ideally, the Docker container should only contain the code needed to run Node.js and the JavaScript code of the React application (plus JavaScript libraries - albeit compiled from original TypeScript in many cases).
How does one make this happen, as I see a compile only puts my *.ts files into dist/*.js files but I do not see any movement on the node_modules/*.js files to be put anywhere.
Is there no way to do this to keep my Docker image small so uploads from CI/CD are very quick?
I tried the basic tutorials but they all seem to include all the extra files.

What does your current Dockerfile look like?  A typical setup here would use a multi-stage build, with a first stage running something like RUN npm run build, and then the second stage only installing production dependencies and only copying the result of the build in, but not the original source files.

" I see a compile only puts my .ts files into dist/.js" - can you clarify which part you talk about "client" or "server"? The result of client build is dist folder, client/node_modules isn't needed to run it and doesn't need to be in a container. And "server" part doesn't work this way, its naturally relies on node_modules, and it's unsafe and hacky to try to clean its contents to slim it down. You could use a bundler with node app too instead of just compiling it with tsc, except that you may have various exotic problems when doing this because this is a possible but not a common approach

@EstusFlask ah, ok, then for client, just copy files from my build/* .  cool!!!  For server, I basically must have build/* and node_modules/* .  Ok, that is a little better though I wish I did not need to include all the useless *.ts files in node_modules in production.  Kind of disappointing but ok.

@DavidMaze I do not understand as I gave a link to github which has the Dockerfile.

@DeanHiller Use a bundler for server part if you want to improve this - webpack, rollup, vite, anything, there are related third-party plugins for node apps, search for "express + bundler name" for some reading. It's doable but it's an edge case
